# Как можно заблокировать поток когда пул переполнен?

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня есть такой тестовый код:

```
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    System.out.println("Starting adding new messages to pool");
    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        pool.submit(() -> {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                System.out.println("Done!");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
    System.out.println("End of the program");
    Thread.sleep(10_000);
```

Если его запустить, то я увижу это:

```
Starting adding new messages to pool
End of the program
Done!
Done!
Done!
Done!
Done!
Done!
Done!
Done!
Done!
```

Но мне надо сделать так, чтобы продьюсер пула потоков блокировался при заполнении буффера и в консоле я бы тогда получил:

```
Starting adding new messages to pool
Done!
Done!
Done!
Done!
Done!
Done!
Done!
Done!
Done!
```

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: `продьюсер пула потоков блокировался` это имеется ввиду, что `submit` должен блокироваться, если нет свободных потоков?

Comment: @RomanKonoval да

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// завершаем работу ExecutorService (ExecutorService продолжит обрабатывать оставшийся список задач, но нельзя будет добавить новые).
pool.shutdown();
// блокируем текущий поток в ожидании завершения задач или таймаута, что произойдет раньше
pool.awaitTermination(600, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Дополнение:

Если нужно блокировать цикл for, когда пул заполнен, то следует применить семафор:

```
final int threads = 1;
// сделаем семафор на threads разрешений
final Semaphore lock = new Semaphore(threads);
ExecutorService pool =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);

System.out.println("Starting adding new messages to pool");
for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
    // запрашиваем разрешение, acquire() грубо говоря повышает счетчик в семафоре на +1, и если этот счетчик равен threads, то метод заблокирует поток, пока счетчик не станет меньше threads (а это произойдет при вызове release())
    lock.acquire();

    pool.submit(() -> {
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
            System.out.println(new Date() + " Done! ");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                lock.release();
            }
        });


        // небольшой костылёк, который реализует ожидание последних threads (кол-во) задач 
        if (i == 60 - 1) {
            lock.acquire(threads);
        }
    }

    lock.release(threads);

    System.out.println("End of the program");
    Thread.sleep(10_000);
```

Comment: Но мне не надо завершать работу `ExecutorService`, мне надо просто блокировать поставщика данных в поток.

Comment: Обновил, посмотрите

Comment: а я уже начал делать через `SynchronousQueue`. Выше решение более простое, спасибо. :)

Comment: @ВасилийНикпуп Это каким боком семафоры проще-то?  Ты правильно стал копать в сторону `SynchonousQueue`, но не докопал. См. мой ответ

Answer (score 0):

Cредствами Явы, без самописных велосипедов

**UPD** Без самописных велосипедов не обошлось, но размер велосипеда меньше, чем с семафорами.

```java
// велосипед
private static boolean interruptibleInfiniteOffer(BlockingQueue<Runnable> q, Runnable r) {
    try {
        return q.offer(r, Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS); // infinite == ~292 years
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public static ThreadPoolExecutor getFixedSizePoolWithLimitedWaitingQueue(int nThreads, int maxItemsInTheQueue) {
    BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = maxItemsInTheQueue == 0
            ? new SynchronousQueue<>() { public boolean offer(Runnable r) { return interruptibleInfiniteOffer(this, r);} }
            : new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(maxItemsInTheQueue) { public boolean offer(Runnable r) { return interruptibleInfiniteOffer(this, r);} };
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads, 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    int nThreads = 4;
    int maxItemsInTheQueue = 1;
    ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = getFixedSizePoolWithLimitedWaitingQueue(nThreads, maxItemsInTheQueue);

    System.out.println("Starting adding new messages to pool");

    final Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        final int t = i;

        System.out.println("Adding task "+t+"...");
        tpe.submit(() -> {
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(50 + random.nextInt(50));
                System.out.println("Task "+t+" is completed");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Task "+t+" is added");
    };

    tpe.shutdown();
    System.out.println("End of the program");
}
```

С помощью параметра `maxItemsInTheQueue` можно регулировать, сколько элементов может ожидать в очереди. Если 0, используем `SynchronousQueue` (задачи в очередь не попадают, продюсеры ждут освободившийся поток), если больше - то `ArrayBlockingQueue` (задачи попадают в очередь до заполнения, потом продюсеры начинают ждать освободившийся поток).

Дополнительно, можно `offer(r, Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)` сделать настраиваемым так, что ожидание свободного слота в очереди будет не бесконечным, а с таймаутом.

Comment: Что-то не работает https://onlinegdb.com/SJJmJVGXd

Comment: Да, забыл за давностью лет, что `ThreadPool` использует `offer`, который не ждёт. Поправил ответ.